# Random image display using rand()

Tags: iphone, uiimage, random

Im just fiddling around with small apps, trying to learn the SDK and ObjC 2.

Im trying to display an image randomly and I keep finding different ways up displaying a picture.  I have uploaded the picture into the SDKs resources folder.

Anyway, here is my code.  Can someone steer me  in the right direction.

```
#import "randomViewController.h"

@implementation randomViewController


//not sure if this is the right way to do it really.
NSArray *comImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"rock.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"scissors.png"],
      nil];


- (IBAction) randButton {
 int text = rand() % 3;
 switch (text) {
  case 0:
   textView.text = @"Rock";
   break;
  case 1:
   textView.text = @"Paper";
   break;
  case 2:
   textView.text = @"Scissors";
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "I keep finding different ways up displaying a picture". And please format the code. Thanks.

Comment: I didnt know how to format the code so I just put it in, sorry.
Basically what Im saying is I see people doing this differently and I cant make sense of it.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rock.png", @"paper.png", @"scissors.png", nil];
int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];
myUIImageView.image = myImage;
```

Obviously you can hold on to myImageNames so you don't have to recreate it every run if you deem it worthwhile.

**Edit:**
Got it. See the updated code. It assumes you have already added a UIImageView called myUIImageView to your view. I assume you know how to do this if you already have a UIButton on the screen.

To add a UIImageView:

Declare the UIImageView *myUIImageView in your header.
Place this in your viewDidLoad assuming you use an xib:

```
myUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[self.view addSubview:myUIImageView];
```

Replace x, y, width and height with the appropriate values. They will determine where in the view the UIImageView appears and how large it is.

Comment: So, am i replacing the "blah, foo, bar" with the image names like "rock.png" etc?

and do i put it all in the -(IBAction)?

Comment: Yes, and yes. It's a little unclear what you are doing though, as you never use your images in the above code.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is display a random picture when I push the "button".  Its acting as the computers choice for the rock paper scissors.  

Im just not sure how to go about it and I figured this would be the best way to do it.  Im just starting to learn it.

Comment: you would think I would know how to do that, but looks can be deceiving ha ha.  Im just learning the relationships between the different classes and methods.  Getting a feel of it all.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

To display images, you want to add a `UIImageView` and set its `image` property to whatever `UIImage` you want. Look at David's answer to see how to get a random image using `objectAtIndex:`, then set the `image` property of your image view to that.